# Laravel 4: Input::all() returns no data with $.ajax POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

In the process of learning Laravel 4, so please pardon me if my question sounds silly.

I am trying to use $.ajax to post form data to the controller.
Upon checking the controller, Input::all() is not populated with data at all.

Have checked that the form is already serialized in the jquery codes.
So now I am here seeking help to see if anyone know how to resolve this issue.

Below is what I have coded so far.

**Jquery Code**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var BASE = "<?php echo Request::root(); ?>/signup/add";
    $('#password').on('blur', function() {
        var info = $('.info');

        $.ajax({
            url:BASE,
            method:'post',
            contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            cache:false,
            dataType:'json',
            data: $("#membersignup").serialize(),
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error:function(xhr,status,error){
                //errors here
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**route.php**

```
Route::post('signup/add', array('uses'=>'MemberController@store'));
```

**MemberController.php**

```
public function store()
{
    return Response::json(Input::all());
}
```

Comment: Is the URL being posted to correct? What response is shown in your console?

Comment: an empty array. The url should be correct since the script is getting a response from the controller.

Comment: Is `CSRF` being enabled? Did you put `CSRF token` in your form and submit it with other data? If not, try adding CSRF token to your `data`.

Comment: Nope, I think I tried doing that before but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the `url` using this:

```
var BASE = "<?php echo Request::root(); ?>/signup/add";
```

Use a named route like this:

```
Route::post('signup/add', array('uses' => 'MemberController@store', 'as' => 'signup.add'));
```

So, it'll be easier for you to generate the `url` for your `ajax` request, using something like this:

```
var BASE = "<?php echo route('signup.add'); ?>
```

This may not solve your problem if you are still generating the right `url` but this will generate the right `url` for sure. I doubt that, you are not sending the request to the right `url` but not sure.

Comment: When using (var BASE = "<?php echo route('signup.add'); ?>), error (Route [signup.add] not defined.) occurs.

When using (Route::post('signup/add', array('uses' => 'MemberController@store', 'as' => 'signup.add'));), console.log() shows (Array[0]). Data is still not populated.

Comment: Did you use `'as' => 'signup.add'` in your route and did you `composer dump-autoload` from command line ?

Comment: Also make sure `$("#membersignup").serialize()` grabs form data and sends to the server.

Comment: That's the issue I am trying to solve. I don't think the data is sent to the server, yet the url path etc all seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is still no accepted answer, I have just had a similar problem and it was fixed by removing the `dataType` option and allowing it to select automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set your contentType like this...

$.ajax({
        url:BASE,
        method:'post',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        cache:false,
        dataType:'json',
        data: $("#membersignup").serialize(),
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(xhr,status,error){
            //errors here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -4):

My guess is that the **$.ajax** is not working for **jquery-1.11.0.min.js**.

Changed to **$.post** and you will have Input::all() working.

Comment: You really think a major version of jQuery shipped with `$.ajax` not working? `$.post` just uses `$.ajax` anyways.